# How to add startup applications in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, startup-applications

Is there a 'Startup applications' app for lubuntu?
Or how do I add apps to startup? I attempted a tutorial to add entries to `~/.config/autostart`, but it did not work. Isn't there an easy way? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 29):

There is a default application for this on the Lubuntu. Check it out:

1. Press the Lubuntu icon on the bottom left;
2. Select **"Preferences"** > **"Default applications for LXSession"**;
3. In the opened window, select the option **"Autostart"**;
4. Now you can enable or disable the autostarted applications, check/uncheck one in the listm or set manually on the field and pressing the **"Add"** button.

Answer (score 19):

You can install the programm `lxsession-edit` from the software center. It will give you an interface like the "startup applications" app.

Or you can add programs by editing the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`. (In new Lubuntu is path `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`)
To do this press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit`.

Or the cleanest way (that didn't work for you) adding .desktop files to `/home/username/.config/autostart` and make sure they're marked as executables.

Here is a default syntax for a `.desktop` file with some of the most important entries.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name="NAME OF THE APPLICATION"
Comment="WHAT DOES THE APP DO?"
Exec="EXECUTABLE PATH OF APPLICATION"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

**Example:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox
Comment=Firefox Web Browser
Exec=firefox
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

For applications that have their binaries in `/usr/bin`, you don't have to put the full path, just the name of the executable.

Save as `YOUR_APPNAME.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart/`.

Log out and back in and it should have worked.

Comment: Thanks, that is part of lubuntu 12.04. But I need to ADD new applications to the startup list.

Comment: Let's go for the cleanest way again. How do I create and format a .desktop file properly? Easy ways preferred.

Comment: I'm trying for per user startup.

Comment: alright I'll write a walkthrough for you as soon as I'm home cause my phone won't get the formatting right

Comment: oh were there anymore problems? Because my answer was unaccepted

Comment: I've tried this and a thousand other things, but nothing works. Absolutely zero things happen every time I restart my computer.

Answer (score 6):

In Lubuntu 18.10 onwards (i.e. with LXQt):

1. Lubuntu icon on bottom left (start button);
2. Preferences;
3. LXQt settings;
4. Session Settings (or LXQt Configuration Centre, followed by Session Settings);
5. In the window that opens, select "Autostart" on the left, then click "Add" on the right.

You can also remove items from the Autostart list by unchecking their boxes - as long as you know what you're removing.

Comment: Any idea how to do this on command line?

Comment: This approach worked for me !  I used it to adjust monitor gamma; less blue. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This works for Lubuntu based on Ubuntu 18.10:
Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Session Settings -> Autostart

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the .desktop file to the directory you listed: `~/.config/autostart`

Did you log out and back in?

The easiest way I have found to do this is to:

1. Open up PCmanFM and go to `/usr/share/applications`.
2. Find the application you're looking for and copy it.
3. Open up `~/.config/autostart` in PCmanFM.
4. Paste in the application you copied.
5. Logout

Once you log back in, it should be working. If it's not, it may be a question of the app, not the autostart process. Which app are you trying to autostart? Maybe we can help you better with more details.