# Setting Xmodmap on login in Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, xmodmap

I installed Lubuntu 13.10, and I'm observing a different behavior of xmodmap than in previous versions. I have a `~/.Xmodmap` file that maps the Caps Lock key to the Ctrl key. Executing `modmap ~/.Xmodmap` works as expected. However, the `.Xmodmap` file is ignored during the login process. In another machine with Lubuntu 13.04 the `.Xmodmap` is read automatically during the login process.

I tried adding a line to `/home/ajw/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` that call a script that set the `xmodmap`, but this is ignored.

According to this [link](http://www.madebits.com/blog/comments.php?y=13&m=11&entry=entry131113-131149), somewhere during the login process the xmodmap setting is undo by a call to `setxkbmap`.

Any idea about how to set xmodmap automatically in Lubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems using Ubuntu, but I solved them using the `sleep` command. This way any other processes won't undo my Xmodmap.

My startup command: `sh -c 'sleep 2 && /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/username/.Xmodmap'`

And [this (How to add startup applications in lubuntu?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159008/how-to-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu) might help.