# How to run automatically Docky at lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, docky

in general: How can I make an application automatically start when I have logged in?

Comment: This could help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159008/how-to-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu

Comment: Or this : [link](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=111&f=8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incredibly easy to do:

Right-click on the left-most icon on the Docky launcher, and click Settings. This opens a new window. At the top, make sure Start When User Logs In is checked.